# await fetch Angular between components via Input

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm making a request with fetch to the reqres api users in app.component, then i share data to his child component (hello.component) via Input. I get the correct user names in child template, I'm trying to print the users in console but i get an empty array. It's there a way to 'await' the response of another component? i guess this is an asynchronous issue. Here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b3m1kp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Thanks in advance.

app.component:

```js
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  public usuarios;

  constructor(){
   this.usuarios = [];
  }

ngOnInit(){
  this.getUsers();
}

getUsers(){
  fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(users => {
        this.usuarios = users.data;
        console.log(this.usuarios);

    });
}

}
```

hello.component:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1 *ngFor="let user of usuarios">Hello {{user.first_name}} </h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent{
  @Input() usuarios;

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.usuarios);
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```html
<hello [usuarios]="usuarios"></hello>
```

Comment: The Stackblitz link you provided prints array of items to the console.

Comment: Use ngOnChanges to detect changes in usuarios array. As the operation is async, the array would be empty at initialization. You can also look into EventEmitters if you do not want to use onChanges.

Comment: yes, its the response from app.component fetch, if i print usuarios in console in hello.component (child component) i get an empty array

Comment: Thanks Berk, ngOnChanges seems to works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the fetch operation is asynchronous, usuarios array would be empty upon initialization for the child. To detect the value changes move logic which will use the fetched results to ngOnChanges.
Like this:

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const { previousValue, currentValue } = changes.usuarios;
    if (previousValue !== currentValue) {
      console.log(this.usuarios);
    }
  }
```

Having a condition to check if the value has changed inside ngOnChanges is essential, otherwise the logic will be constantly triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<hello *ngIf="usuarios.length>0" [usuarios]="usuarios"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```